# Is there any event executed when the value of textarea changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a simplified snippet of my code:

```js
$("#textarea_id").on('input propertychange', function(e){
 alert('the value of textarea changed');
});

$("#bold").on('click', function(e){
 $("#textarea_id").val('bold');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id = "textarea_id"></textarea>
<br>
<button id = "bold">
B
</button>
```

I want to see that `alert` when the value of that textarea changes *(in any way)*. As you see it just runs when we write something into that textarea, but not when we click on that button *(while it should be, because when we click on that button, the value of that textarea changes)*. How can I make it sensitive for every kind of changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `change` event. However programmatically changing value will not automatically trigger the event handler.

To trigger the event handler, [`trigger(event)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) can be used.

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Also note: `.change()` is just shorthand for `.trigger('change')`

```js
$("#textarea_id").on('input change', function(e){
 alert('the value of textarea changed');
});

$("#bold").on('click', function(e){
 $("#textarea_id").val('bold').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id = "textarea_id"></textarea>
<br>
<button id = "bold">
B
</button>
```